# How to fill blank SharePoint List Lookup field with default value using json

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

The following is part of JSON formatting in a SP List that turns rows red if field `LookupFieldX` is empty:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if(length([$LookupFieldX.lookupValue])==0,'ms-bgColor-red','ms-bgColor-white'))))+ ' ms-fontColor-black'"
}
```

How do I extend the JSON so the empty field displays "TBD" in addition to the entire row being red? As you know, column formatting does not work for this because it is a lookup field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup field supports JSON column formatting, see [Supported column types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types).

For your requirements, use this JSON:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "=if(@currentField.lookupValue, @currentField.lookupValue, 'TBD')"
}
```

**Before applying JSON**:

[image]

**After applying JSON**:

[image]

---

Follow these steps to apply column formatting:

1. Go to List view.
2. To open the column formatting pane, open the drop-down menu under a lookup column name/header.
3. Under **Column Settings**, choose **Format this column**.
4. Make sure you have selected "Format columns" option & `LookupFieldX` under "Choose Column" dropdown like:

[image]